# ParseError not in scope - "Scheme in 48 hours"

Tags: haskell, ghc, parsec

(noob alert) I'm going through [Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours); however I get a "not in scope: ParseError" message upon compilation of the code pertaining to Ch.4, Error Checking and Exceptions (following the tutorial 1:1 , no need to repeat it here).
I use GHC 7.6.3.
The import section :

```
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)
```

but I also tried adding `import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Error` and `import Text.Parsec.Error`, to no avail.
It seems like the ParseError ADT is exposed by a few different libraries, but for some reason the compiler doesn't see it. Other Parsec functionality instead works just fine.

Any pointers? Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: sure! please find it here: https://gist.github.com/ocramz/39b60daedc4ae3bec5df

Comment: although I have checked it a few times already with the original at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/LaTeX#errorcheck.hs ; the declarations are only in a different order to follow the tutorial step by step

Comment: In case someone—like I just did ;)—stumbles upon this question while trying to find a way to create a `ParseError` value: the constructors for `ParseError` (and `SourcePos`) apparently are not exported anywhere within the relevant modules. However, there is a constructor function `newErrorUnknown` provided in `Text.Parsec.Error` ([Link to Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html)) and for `SourcePos` there is `newPos` in `Text.Parsec.Pos` ([Link to Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Pos.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The fix came from replacing the variable names in one function declaration:

WRONG:

```
showError :: LispError -> String
showError (UnboundVar msg varname) = msg ++ ": " ++ varname
showError (BadSpecialForm msg frm) = msg ++ ": " ++ show frm
showError (NotFunction msg f) = msg ++ ": " ++ show f
showError (NumArgs expected found) = "Expected " ++ show expected ++ " args: found values     " ++ unwordsList found
showError (TypeMismatch expected found) = "Invalid type: expected " ++ expected ++ ", found " ++ show found
showError (ParseError pe) = "Parse error at " ++ show pe
```

RIGHT:

```
showError :: LispError -> String
showError (UnboundVar message varname) = message ++ ": " ++ varname
showError (BadSpecialForm message form) = message ++ ": " ++ show form
showError (NotFunction message func) = message ++ ": " ++ show func
showError (NumArgs expected found) = "Expected " ++ show expected 
                              ++ " args: found values " ++ unwordsList found
showError (TypeMismatch expected found) = "Invalid type: expected " ++ expected
                                   ++ ", found " ++ show found
showError (Parser parseErr) = "Parse error at " ++ show parseErr
```

I swear, I don't get it. Any clarification would be highly appreciated.